# secretsmanager rotate-secret race conditions checking AWSPENDING is complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to implement some type of polling mechanism that checks if an AWS Lambda password rotation has actually completed:

From what I understand, a password rotation is completed if:

> The AWSPENDING and AWSCURRENT staging labels are attached to the same version of the secret, or The AWSPENDING staging label is not attached to any version of the secret.

This is what I have so far to check if the rotation is completed:

```
while [ "$rotationComplete" == false ]; do
    versionStages=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id awsSecret --query 'VersionStages' | jq -r .)

    # Check if the rotation is complete
    if [[ " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSPENDING" && " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSCURRENT" ]] || [[ ! " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSPENDING" ]]; then
        echo "Secret rotation completed."
        rotationComplete=true
    else
        echo "Secret rotation has not completed yet. Waiting..."
        attempt=$((attempt + 1)) 
        sleep 30  #   
    fi  
done
```

Is there anything else I should check like versionId to check if the password rotation has actually completed?

Comment: Are you implementing a custom rotation lambda or are you just wanting to verify when automatic rotation is complete? What are the credentials in the secret for?

Comment: @ThomasBoudreau We are using AWS RDS Postgres Single user https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py and when we call this via CLI it always returns 200 (Success), however, we have found that doesn't actually mean the secret has rotated. So I am looking for a way to verify that it has actually rotated. The credentials are a single user in Postgres consisting of password, username, etc

Comment: Are you saying you're invoking the rotation Lambda once through the CLI and that Lambda execution succeeds with a 200? What input are you providing the Lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have found to be the most reliable way to check that an AWS secret password has **actually** rotated. This is a method of "polling" the AWS secret to verify that the password has successfully been rotated.

Some points:

- You want to verify that there is a **NEW** version ID
- Check that versionStages has the tags `AWSPENDING` and `AWSCURRENT` OR is not equal to `AWSPENDING`
- I have a `maxAttempts` check so that I don't get stuck in an infinite loop. There may  be a case where the label gets stuck on `AWSPENDING` in which you will have to call `update-secret-version-stage` to remove that label.

```
versionIdBeforeRotateSecret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ID> --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE>--query 'VersionId' | jq -r .)
# rotate secret
aws --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE> secretsmanager rotate-secret --secret-id <YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ID>
rotationComplete=false
attempt=1
maxAttempts=5
secret_info=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ID> --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE>)
versionId=$(echo "$secret_info" | jq -r '.VersionId')
versionStages=($(echo "$secret_info" | jq -r '.VersionStages[]'))
while [ "$rotationComplete" == false ] && [ "$attempt" -le "$maxAttempts" ]; do        
  if [[ " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSPENDING" && " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSCURRENT" ]] || [[ ! " ${versionStages[@]} " =~ "AWSPENDING" ]] && [ "$versionId" != "$versionIdBeforeRotateSecret" ]; then
      echo "Secret rotation completed."
      rotationComplete=true
  else
        echo "Secret rotation has not completed yet. Waiting..."
        attempt=$((attempt + 1)) 
        sleep 60  # 
  fi  
  done
done
```